# Exercise 15, chapter 9 of O'Neill's "Semi-Riemannian geometry"

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity

I am stuck with the following exercise (exercise 15, chapter 9) in O'Neill's book on semi-Riemannian geometry:

"Let $M$ be a complete and connected semi-Riemannian manifold of dimension $n$. Show that the following statements are equivalent:

1) The isometry group of $M$ has dimension $n(n+1)/2$.

2) The algebra of Killing vector fields of $M$ has dimension $n(n+1)/2$.

3) Given any two points $p,q\in M$ and any linear isometry $\Lambda:T_pM\to T_q M$, there exists an isometry $\sigma:M\to M$ such that $\sigma(p)=q$ and $d\sigma_p=\Lambda$."

I have no problem in showing 1) $\Rightarrow$ 2) and 3) $\Rightarrow$ 1), but I cannot show 2) $\Rightarrow$ 3).

More specifically: given 2), it is clear to me that 3) with $p=q$ will hold whenever $\Lambda$ is connected to the identity, but I cannot see why it should hold also for $\Lambda$ not connected to the identity.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see a  great way to get from $2$ to $3$.  Instead, I think I would try to go from $2$ back to $1$, and then go from $1$ to $3$.  (That said, I don't know much about semi-Riemannian things.  For example, does the Hopf-Rinow theorem from Riemannian geometry still hold in this setting?)

Comment: If you could explain how to go from 1) to 3) that would be a completely satisfactory answer for me (for $M$ complete, the algebra of Killing fields is anti-isomorphic to the Lie algebra of the isometry group of $M$, so the equivalence between 1) and 2) is clear). The Hopf-Rinow theorem does not hold in semi-Riemannian geometry, as there is an example of a Lorentzian manifold, the Clifton-Pohl torus, which is compact but not complete (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifton–Pohl_torus).

Comment: Actually, the part from Hopf-Rinow I was thinking of is "complete $\implies$ any two points have a minimizing geodesic between them" - but that Clifton-Pohl torus is a cool example.  Anyway, here's a sketch for the Riemannian case.  Perhaps it is not too hard to adapt to the semi-Riemannian case?  Let $FM\rightarrow M$ denote the frame bundle.  Any isometry of $M$ induces a bundle isomorphism of $FM$.  The kicker is the following statement:  $f_1,f_2$ induce the same bundle isomorphism iff $f_1 = f_2$, which boils down to the following statement:  If $f$ is an isometry with $f(p) = p$ and...

Comment: $d_p f = Id$, then $f = Id$.  Once you have proven that, note that the group of isometries, acting on $M$ gives an embedding $G$ into $FM$ by first fixing a point $p\in M$ and frame $\{v_i\}$ at $p$ and then using $g\rightarrow (gp, g_\ast \{v_i\})$.  By the "kicker", this map is injective.  But $\dim FM = n(n+1)/2$.  It follows that this embedding is a diffeo.  In particular, $G$ can move any point to any other and any frame to any other.  (Gotta run to class for the next while, but I will eventually respond to any comments you have!)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's a very clear argument. The only part of it I don't understand is the implication "$f:G\to FM$ is injective and $\dim G=\dim FM$ $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is a diffeomorphism". For example, consider a manifold $M$ and an open subset $U$ of $M$. $U$ and $M$ have the same dimension, and the inclusion map $U\to M$ is injective, but it is not a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Yes, there is a gap there.  I guess was implicitly assuming $G$ was compact.  Then the image would be closed for free, and open by the dimension assumption, so, by conectedness, it would be everything.  I will think about how to patch up the argument in the general case...

Comment: Kobayashi, Transformation Groups in Dif Geo, Thm 3.2 and Lemma 2 prove the image G in FM is closed,which is enough for my argument to carry through.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, it will probably be helpful. I think FM is in general not connected even though $M$ is (for example, if $M$ is the $n$-dimensional Euclidean space we have $FM={\mathbb R}^n\times O(n)$, which is not connected because O(n) is not connected), and hence the fact that the image of $G$ in $FM$ is both open and closed is not enough to conclude that it is equal to $FM$.

Comment: Another gap!  If $M$ is non-orientable, then $FM$ will be connected, so the argument seems to work in that case.  I will continue to think.  (In the Riemannian case, what we have argued is already enough to show $M$ has constant sectional curvature.  Such (complete) $M$ have been classified.  I have no idea what happens in semi-Riemannian geometry)